# how to calculate the current in this circuit ( opamp)

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, current-measurement

how to calculate the current in this circuit (show with the green arrow)
Can someone explain with a bit of details.
In the books i got from school, they dont come close to what this looks like.

[image: circuit]

Comment: What is this cross symbol supposed to be ?
I can guess it's a lamp, so I'll assume its pretty much a 1k resistor.
The voltage across the 2k resistor would be 0v (due to ideal opamp assumptions), hence the current though R would be 10/2k = 5mA

Comment: @Mike,  the voltage across the 2k resistor would be 10 V due to ideal opamp assumptions.

Comment: It would be 0v referenced to ground. And 10v referenced to the op amp negative rail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this circuit the op amp will drive its output up or down until the - input is at the same voltage as the + input (or until the output hits one of the supply rails). The + input is connected to ground, so the - input will become 0V and R will have 10V across it. 10V / 2k = 5mA.

Comment: ...and that is correct because on top of the 1k resistor/lamp you would have 5V, that is below 10V. If the 2k resistor was a 200\$\Omega\$ resistor, the solution 10V/200\$\Omega\$=50mA would have been *wrong*.